# Mockito @InjectMocks not assigned a @Spy to the correct field

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I have a simple test case with a spied List of Mocked Objects that I then Inject into the class being tested

```
@Spy List<ValidateRule> ruleServices = new ArrayList<>();

@Mock
private EvaluateGroupType evaluateGroupType;

@Mock
private ValidateServiceRule validateServiceRule;

@InjectMocks
private ValidateRulesService validateRulesService;

@Before
public void init() throws Exception {
    initMocks(this);
}
```

However, in the *ValidateRulesService* class the list is being injected to the wrong list.

```
List<Integer> demonstrationList = new ArrayList<>();

@Autowired
private List<ValidateRule> ruleServices;
```

[image]

I have also tried to inject it as a using Constructor injection and here the results are that the values are being Injected twice

```
List<Integer> demonstrationList = new ArrayList<>();

final private List<ValidateRule> ruleServices;

@Autowired
public ValidateRulesService(List<ValidateRule> ruleServices) {
    this.ruleServices = ruleServices;
}
```

[image]

I'm not expecting *DemonstationList* to have any values in either circumstance. As it doesn't have the same name or is of the same type as *rulesService* based on what I have read in the docs for [@injectmocks](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.5.0/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html).

Am i doing something wrong here, or is this a quirk of Mockito?

Comment: any reason why you have to spy the list? mocking and set-up is not enough?

Comment: @MaciejKowalski While that might result in a more clean test, it would likely still result in the same issue though.

Comment: you can specify a name of the field to inject into if you use Mock

Comment: If you Mock the list you cannot add mocked objects to it.

Comment: You could set it up.. just bit more hustle thats true

Answer (score 2):

There are two things at play here. First of all, **generics do not exist at runtime**, so basically Mockito sees both `List` instances and then should pick one. The second issue is that your field is declared as `final`, which Mockito will skip when injecting mocks/spies.

With Mockito 1.x (this is the default when using Spring boot 1.x), you can't change this behaviour as far as I'm aware, so the only solution is to inject the fields by yourself in a `@SetUp` method:

```
private ValidateRulesService validateRulesService;
@Spy
private List<ValidateRule> ruleServices = new ArrayList<>();

@Before
public void setUp() {
    // Inject the mocks/spies by yourself
    validateRulesService = new ValidateRulesService(ruleServices);
}
```

This is also mentioned in [Robert Mason's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47771617).

With Mockito 2.x on the other hand, it will prioritize fields using the same field name as the spy/mock, as you can see in [the documentation](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.13.0/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html):

> **Field injection**; mocks will first be resolved by type (if a single type match injection will happen regardless of the name), then, if there is several property of the same type, by the match of the field name and the mock name.

And also:

> **Note 1**: If you have fields with the same type (or same erasure), it's better to name all @Mock annotated fields with the matching fields, otherwise Mockito might get confused and injection won't happen.

However, be aware that if you use Mockito 2, it will ignore `final` fields when it injects the mocks/spies:

> The same stands for setters or fields, they can be declared with private visibility, Mockito will see them through reflection. **However fields that are static or final will be ignored**.

*(Emphasis is my own)*

So, if you use Mockito 2.x, it should correctly inject the `ruleServices` if you remove the `final` keyword.

Comment: I've removed final but it still populates both lists when using Constructor injection.

The second list "deomonstrationList" should not be mocked at all in this test case.

Comment: @RobertMason and what if you removed the `final` keyword and used field injection? This should work now, if both your spy and your actual field are named `ruleService`.

Comment: At the top of the question, you'll see that, that was my first implementation, to use field injection with the same name. 

But for some reason it seems to want to set it to the *DemonstationList*

Comment: @RobertMason yes, but that was caused by the `final` field, now that you've removed it, it should be able to set the `ruleService`.

Comment: Unfortunately even without final it is not injecting it to the correct field.

I've managed to get Constructor injection working however, and i will post my answer below.

Why it is adding it to the wrong List even when the names don't match or the types aren't the same i still don't know!

Comment: @RobertMason with the names, I have no clue yet, however, be aware that the types are the same, both are a `List`.

Comment: @RobertMason You're right, the documentation I quoted is from Mockito 2.x while Spring boot 1.x uses Mockito 1.x by default. However, if you change the `mockito-core` version to 2.x, it should work as I mentioned. I clarified that in my answer now.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get this to correctly mock the correct list by altering the constructor injection implementation

The test

```
@Spy
List<ValidateRule> ruleServices = new ArrayList<>();

@Mock
private EvaluateGroupType evaluateGroupType;

@Mock
private ValidateServiceRule validateServiceRule;

private ValidateRulesService validateRulesService;

@Before
public void init() throws Exception {
    initMocks(this);
    ruleServices = Arrays.asList(evaluateGroupType, validateServiceRule);
    validateRulesService = new ValidateRulesService(ruleServices);
}
```

The Class being tested

```
private List<ValidateRule> ruleServices;
private List<ResponseTo> responseToList = new ArrayList<>();

@Autowired
public ValidateRulesService(List<ValidateRule> ruleServices) {
    this.ruleServices = ruleServices;
}
```